# Why RegionMeasure returns a complex value?

Tags: bugs, regions

**Bug introduced in 12.1 or earlier and persisting through 13.2**

---

Consider the following region:

```
region = BooleanRegion[#1 || #2 &, {Circle[{0, 0}, 
   63.01771474209481`, {-0.3085423746716913`, 0}], 
  Circle[{0, 0}, 63.01771474209481`, {0, 0.3085423746716913`}]}]
```

Why in Mathematica 12.1 `RegionMeasure[region]` returns a complex value, and how to avoid it without dealing with explicit calculations (despite the fact that it is possible to make this easily)?

```
RegionMeasure[region]
```

> 38.8873 + 0.0000128693 I

Comment: Machine precision calculations neither track nor control precision. You get what you get. Arbitrary precision will track and attempt to control precision. Exact numbers will give exact results.

Comment: Per the tag wiki for [tag:bugs]: "Please do not use this tag for new questions."  -- Now, does the community think it's a bug?

Comment: I think it is a bug. Worth reporting to the support. Added the BUG header and the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is numerical inaccuracy stemming from your machine precision inputs. Setting a `WorkingPrecision` for `RegionMeasure` takes care of the problem:

````
RegionMeasure[region, WorkingPrecision -> 10]

(* Out: 38.88727071 *)
```
````

Comment: Why not `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision`? (Why so much less than?) -- Oh, bizarre. It makes no difference. But I usually use `WorkingPrecision -> 16` because it's shorter to type, and that works. -- Oh, wow, `WorkingPrecision -> 10.` fails, too. That's wierd.

Comment: Hmm, `WorkingPrecision -> p` seems to work only if `p` is an integer (fails for `Real` and `Rational`).

Comment: @MichaelE2 This looks like a bug in `WorkingPrecision` functionality. Worth reporting to support.